# Display GitLab repositories of the logged in user on a page

Tags: git

I am new at wordpress and i am create a website with all my details and accomplishments. I want to display all my GitLab repository names and links as a list on a page (not as a menu or widget). I have already created a public access token. to be used for API.

Comment: There's several ways you can do this, e.g. make a specific template for that page in your theme which includes extra HTML to show your list, or add a plugin that adds a short code to render the list, or you can probably a Gutenberg block for this too (but I don't really know Gutenberg). Or even some per-page script that fetches the data from your own API endpoint (that wraps and caches the GitLab API) and then render the data client-side.

Comment: In terms of fetching the data, you'll need to write code to make the GitLab API request and then cache this in a [transient](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/) so that you don't make an API request every single time the page is loaded. You can then provide this data to whatever mechanism above you choose to render it, probably just through a direct function call. This should go in your plugin or theme.